# Parsing using sscanf doesn't preserve arrays for subsequent use

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, fgets, scanf

I'm working on a project that simulates an n-way associative cache mapping. However, the problem arises when trying to use the address[i] array in a subsequent equation. I guess I'm not understanding why the array isn't being preserved. Any help would be very much appreciated. I'm not the best with C coding. Right now the problem is with reading from the file and scanning those values into arrays. Everything else I'm confident I can figure out.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


/*global variables */
int mainSize, cacheSize, blockSize, cmSet, cnumBlocks, mnumBlocks,address[50],mmBlkNum[50], mappedCMset[50],hit_miss[50],address[50];
char mode[50];
int totMemRefs=0;


int main(void)
{
    /*Variables */

    int i;
    char replacePolicy;
    char filename[50];
    char *result = NULL;
    char line[50];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");


    /*Gathers input from user */
    printf("Enter the main memory size between between 4 and 32K bytes: ");
    scanf("%d",&mainSize);
    if (mainSize < 4 || mainSize > 32768)
    {
        printf("Invalid main memory size.");
        //errorCheck()
    }

    printf("Enter the size of the cache between 2 and 32K bytes: ");
    scanf("%d", &cacheSize);
    if (cacheSize < 2 || cacheSize > 32768)
    {
        printf("Invalid cache memory size.");
        //errorCheck()
    } 


    printf("Enter the size of the block/line between 2 and 32K bytes: ");
    scanf("%d",&blockSize);
    if (blockSize < 2 || blockSize > 32768)
    {
        printf("Invalid block/line size.");
        //errorCheck
    }

    printf("Enter the degree of set-associativity: ");
    scanf("%d", &cmSet);


    cnumBlocks = cacheSize/blockSize;
    printf("Number of blocks in cache = %d\n", cnumBlocks);

    mnumBlocks = mainSize/blockSize;
    printf("Number of blocks in main memory = %d\n", mnumBlocks);

    printf("Enter replacement policy (L = LRU, F = FIFO): ");
    scanf("%s", &replacePolicy);




    printf("Enter the name of the file containing the list of memory    referenced: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);


    /* checks if filename is valid/exits */
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Invalid input.");
        //errorCheck();
    }

    /* gets total number of mem references from first line of file and stores in variable totMemRefs*/
    fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp);
    result = strtok(line,"\n");
    totMemRefs = atoi(result);
    printf("Total Mem Refs = %d\n", totMemRefs);


    /*skips second line of white space */
    fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp);

    i=0;
    //reads each line of file and tokenizes into mode and address
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)!=NULL)
    {

        if (sscanf(line,"%s %d",&mode[i],&address[i]) == 2)
        {
            printf("Mode: %c  Address: %d\n",mode[i],address[i]);
            i++;
        }


    }//end of parsing while loop

    fclose(fp); //close file after reading


    for (i=0; i<totMemRefs; i++)
    {
        /* calculates the corresponding block number of the address */
        mmBlkNum[i]=address[i]/blockSize;

        /* calculates the corresponding cache mem set that mm block is in */
        mappedCMset[i]=mmBlkNum[i]%cnumBlocks;
        printf("Mode = %c  Address = %d  MM Block Num = %d  Cm Set = %d\n",    mode[i],address[i],mmBlkNum[i],mappedCMset[i]);

    }

}//end of main
```

This is the content of the example_test_data.txt:

```
6

R 0
R 1
R 4
R 36
R 0
R 4
```

These are the characteristics of the main memory and cache memory:

```
main mem size = 128 bytes
cache mem size = 32 bytes
block size = 4 bytes
set associativity = 2
filename = example_test_data.txt
```

This is the output for the arrays in the while loop:

```
    Mode: R  Address: 0
    Mode: R  Address: 1
    Mode: R  Address: 4
    Mode: R  Address: 36
    Mode: R  Address: 0
    Mode: R  Address: 4
```

This is the output for the arrays after parsing -- in the following for loop:

```
    Mode = R  Address = 4  MM Block Num = 1  Cm Set = 1
    Mode =    Address = 0  MM Block Num = 0  Cm Set = 0
    Mode =    Address = 0  MM Block Num = 0  Cm Set = 0
    Mode =    Address = 0  MM Block Num = 0  Cm Set = 0
    Mode =    Address = 0  MM Block Num = 0  Cm Set = 0
    Mode =    Address = 0  MM Block Num = 0  Cm Set = 0
```

As you can see, the second iteration of the mode and address arrays are not the same as the ones in the file while loop. I'm confused as to why this is the case. I tried to be as descriptive as possible. I also don't know why the format didn't show up. Sorry if that makes it harder to read. Again, any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
The output SHOULD BE:

```
    Mode = R   Address = 0   MM Blk Num = 0   CM Set = 0
    Mode = R   Address = 1   MM Blk Num = 0   CM Set = 0
    Mode = R   Address = 4   MM Blk Num = 1   CM Set = 1
    Mode = R   Address = 36  MM Blk Num = 9   CM Set = 1
    Mode = R   Address = 0   MM Blk Num = 0   CM Set = 0
    Mode = R   Address = 4   MM Blk Num = 1   CM Set = 1
```

I know the equations I need to get the correct values. I know how to work these by hand no problem. So knowing what the outcome SHOULD be isn't the problem. 
Previously, I've made use of fscanf and strtok and neither of those produced the desired results. Basically, it works when I print it in the while loop as I'm scanning, but the values in the arrays aren't the same once I try to calculate mmBlkNum and mappedCMset.

Code has been updated!!

Comment: You need to do some work to come up with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Nobody is going to look at your wall of code.  In figuring out the minimal complete example that shows your problem you'll not only help us, but there's a good chance you'll find the problem yourself.

Comment: @davidbak  I've spent days trying to figure out the problem as well as different methods to achieve the goal, and still to no avail. I know what the code SHOULD do, and I added an example of correct output, but I'm not seeing the problem. Thanks for comment nonetheless.

Comment: I would say the opposite of davidbak. Code is not so long, but it's not a complete and verifiable example. Please provide a **full** program which compile, and which you tested to be sure it produces the outputs you indicate with your given inputs (sometimes people removes code to make it smaller and post a program with no error at all in their question).

Comment: @jdarthenay I've added the rest of the code in. It compiles on my system.

Comment: `error: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[50]' [-Werror=format=]`

Comment: Please learn to compile with **at least** `-Wall` and consider using `-Werror` and `-Wextra`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error I see:

```
scanf("%s", &filename);
```

Replace with correct argument:

```
scanf("%s", filename);
```

Please compile with `-Wall` so those things will be said by compiler. Combine with `-Werror`. `-Wextra` is also recommended.

My complier output with your program:

```
stackoverflow.c: In function 'main':
stackoverflow.c:246:11: error: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[50]' [-Werror=format=]
     scanf("%s", &filename);
           ^
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Second error I see: you put all you read at same index `i = 0` in your `while` loop. Either use a `for` or use `while` correctly:

```
    i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)!=NULL && i < totMemRefs)
    {
        if (sscanf(line,"%s %d",&mode[i],&address[i]) == 2)
        {
            printf("Mode: %c  Address: %d\n",mode[i],address[i]);
            i++;
        }


    }//end of parsing while loop

    if (i < totMemRefs)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing inputs.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Also I added verification input does not go beyond the number of inputs user said he will provide, and verification user provide all lines. Consider adding something like that at beginning of program:

```
#define MAX_INPUT_LINES 50
```

and use `MAX_INPUT_LINES` instead of `50`.

Comment: Although I can't vote up your answer due to my low reputation, I sincerely appreciate you taking the time to step through my code!! @jdarthenay I don't have much experience with C, but with the help of people willing to devote a little of their time, I'm learning!! Thank you again!

Comment: @Tmphillips If my answer solves your problem, you're supposed to accept it, it should be somewhere bellow the  score of my answer.